# BibTex problem w/achemso packages

Tags: bibtex, achemso

I am trying to use `achemso` package for my bibliography and having problem with my references. I keep getting error message saying that "`! Improper alphabetic constant. <to be read again> \protectl.26...ed properties \cite{bierbaum03a,stuart08}`". I tried a number of approaches including `\bibliographystyle{achemso}/{biochem}`, but did not work. If you could provide me your suggestion, will be appreciated.

Here is the packages I used:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{achemso}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{hypdoc}
%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
 applications for
generating matrices of tailored properties \cite{bierbaum03a,stuart08}. 

\bibliography{deneme}

\end{document}
```

and my bib file:

```
@article{bierbaum03a,
  title={Modification of {Ti6Al4V} surfaces using collagen {I}, {III}, and fibronectin. {I}. Biochemical and morphological characteristics of the adsorbed matrix},
  author={Bierbaum, S and Beutner, R and Hanke, T and Scharnweber, D and Hempel, U and Worch, H},
  journal={J. Biomed. Mater. Res.-A},
  volume={67},
  number={2},
  pages={421--430},
  year={\textbf{2003}},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@article{stuart08,
  title={Characterization of gels composed of blends of collagen {I}, collagen {III}, and chondroitin sulfate},
  author={Stuart, K and Panitch, A},
  journal={Biomacromolecules},
  volume={10},
  number={1},
  pages={25--31},
  year={\textbf{2008}},
  publisher={ACS Publications}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have any formatting in the BibTeX file, or at least only that which is *essential* (normally in titles). Here, you have

```
year={\textbf{2008}}
```

which should be

```
year={2008}
```

The odd error you get is from `natbib`, which expects to be able to make the year available as a number: formatting breaks that.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Joseph, I have been reading and learning from your posts, since I met with LaTex! Actauly, I have already tried that, before posting my question, but I think that stack made me crazy! Anyway, that WORKED this time. Thanks so much again!!